# Inconsistent search behaviour in XE2?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Find in Files (all files in project, no regexp): "Integer("
("" are not part of the search term) with 'Whole words only' checked 
returns these 6 lines:

```
PlanRoutines.BekijkRefplan( Integer( Items.Objects[ ItemIndex ] ));
PlanRoutines.BekijkRefplan( Integer( Items.Objects[ ItemIndex ] ));
Result := Integer( ComboBoxStatus.Properties.Items.Objects[ ComboBoxStatus.ItemIndex ] );
LNieuweStatus := Integer( ComboBoxNieuweStatus.Properties.Items.Objects[ ComboBoxNieuweStatus.ItemIndex ] );
LVanafStatus  := Integer( ComboBoxVanafStatus.Properties.Items.Objects[ ComboBoxVanafStatus.ItemIndex ] );
LTotStatus    := Integer( ComboBoxNieuweStatus.Properties.Items.Objects[ ComboBoxTotStatus.ItemIndex ] );
```

How come?

I would expect this first search to find *no* results (I accidentally had WWO checked when this happened)

With WWO unchecked, searching for " Integer("  (note the extra space in front) Delphi finds approx 100 lines including those 6 mentioned above.

Even the search dialog itself has weird behaviour:
If I copy or type "Integer(" into the search edit, then insert a space in front, the cursor jumps to the end of "Integer(".
This does not happen if I type another character in front of "Integer(", or if I type a space in front of e.g. "string", "string(" or "String("

Can anyone confirm? What is my Delphi XE2 Update 4 Hotfix 1 (16.0.4504.48759) doing (Win7 64bit)?

It's not a big deal, just curious.

(That initial search result is wrong, but I would not intentially do that search. WWO was still checked from a previous search).

Additional examples that surprise me: with WWO on, search "TMyEventHandlers." -> 0 results, search ":= true" -> 0 results, search "true)" -> plenty results, search "(Sender:" -> 0 results. I do not understand how Delphi behaves here. The only thing I can can conclude right now is 'Better make sure to only have chars/digits' in the search string when checking WWO.

Comment: Is this a question about the search results, or is it a question about the behavior of the insertion caret in the dialog box? If it's a question about the results, then I don't understand the question; the results you've shown certainly seem to match the search term you used, so why *shouldn't* they be returned? If it's a question about the insertion caret, then why do you spend five paragraphs talking about search results before you finally get to the point? Please edit your question to clearly ask a single question, and remove the irrelevant parts. Post two separate questions if you must.

Comment: It's mainly a question about the search result. Since it is unexpected it almost sent me in the wrong direction. Specifically: "I see this is implemented in only 6 places in the code so let's fix the code by method 'A'". Only then I got suspicious about this small number, re-ran the search without WWO, the new outcome made me decide fo fix things differently (method 'B'). Had I not been suspicious I would only have partially solved the issue using A. The insertion caret remarks were added as an aside. That has no such consequences and yes, could've been a different question.

Comment: I will add some additional examples to the original question about 'unexpected'

Comment: You haven't explained why you consider the results you get to be unexpected. I can search *my* code for `TMyEventHandlers.` and get zero results, too, but that's entirely unsurprising. I suspect what you're *really* asking is what effect "whole words only" is supposed to have when the value to search for consist of *more* than a single word. If that's the case, then please edit your question to make that clear, and please remove the irrelevant part about the caret.

Comment: i may have Handbook local var, FHandbook private member and GlobalHandbook singleton. If i do `Search in files` with WWO off and "Handbook :=" pattern - i would get all places where those are assigned. However if i set WWO on - i would only get local var assigned. Makes sense to me. The trailing space though - "Handbook := " pattern would return zero results.

Answer (score 0):

> then insert a space in front, the cursor jumps to the end of "Integer("

cannot confirm. Works like a charm.
win7 x64 / XE2 u4hf1 / Ide FixPack 5.0 / VersionCopntrol-Plus SVN

---

> I would expect this first search to find no results
>   Basically that has little practical sense. Why search to find zero results ? to test IDE ?

To me i formulate WWO behaviour rather simple - both left and right from pattern there whould be distinct separate terms. And within brackets - there are those.

Comment: I did not intentionally do that search. WWO was still checked from a previous search

Comment: u did not. But the ability to make one is unreasonable per se